# I want to create 2D array with 5 rows by 1 column

Tags: julia

If I want to create 2D array with 1 row by 5 columns.
I could do this

```
julia> a = [1 2 3 4 5]
1×5 Array{Int64,2}:
 1  2  3  4  5
```

But to create 2D array with 5 rows by 1 column. I have tried

```
julia> b = [1; 2; 3; 4; 5]
5-element Array{Int64,1}:
 1
 2
 3
 4
 5
```

But I got back a 1D array which is NOT what I wanted

The only way to get it to work is

```
julia> b=reshape([1 2 3 4 5],5,1)
5×1 Array{Int64,2}:
 1
 2
 3
 4
 5
```

Perhaps I am missing some crucial information here.

Answer (score 0):

You could also do `a = [1 2 3 4 5]'`.

On a side note, for Julia versions > 0.6 the type of `a` wouldn't be `Array{Int64, 2}` but a `LinearAlgebra.Adjoint{Int64,Array{Int64,2}}` as conjugate transpose is lazy in this case. One can get <= 0.6 behavior by `a = copy([1 2 3 4 5]')`.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK there is no syntactic sugar for it.

I usually write:

```
hcat([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
```

which is short and I find it easy to remember.

If you use `reshape` you can replace one dimension with `:` which means you do not have to count (it is useful e.g. when you get an input vector as a variable):

```
reshape([1 2 3 4 5], :, 1)
```

Finally you could use:

```
permutedims([1 2 3 4 5])
```